# Can a method somehow get inlined if it's being called from a dynamically allocated object(Compiler optimization)

Tags: c++, optimization, compiler-construction

If I have this code:

```
class MyClass;

class Child   
{  
public:   
    void ExecuteChild()   
    {   
       parent->ExecuteParent(); //This function   
    }

MyClass* parent;   
};

class MyClass    
{    
 public:
   MyClass    
{   
   child = newChild();
   chilt->parent = this;    
}

   void ExecuteParent()    
{       
//does something    
} 

Child* child

};

std::vector<MyClass*> objects;
int num = GetRandomNumberBetween5and10();
for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
  objects.push_back(new MyClass());
}

for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
  objects[i]->Execute());
}
```

Under a modern C++ compiler with all optimizations enabled, is there any possibility for Child::ExecuteParent() to be inlined?I'm asking this, because I have such a similar case in my project at a VERY performance-intense spot and I must know if there is any point in continuing this design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose in principle that method call could be inlined, because the compiler does know the class of `objects[i]`.
I would be surprised if it actually does it.

When you have what you call a "VERY performance-intensive spot" I start to get a whiff of premature optimization, which I define as solving a performance problem before you know for sure if it *is* one.

The thing about performance issues is what makes them so is you *don't* know where they are.
They stow away in your code without your knowledge.
Sometimes trying to solve an imagined performance issue causes the *creation* of performance issues.
What's more, there is never just one of them (in my experience).

For example, suppose you have three performance problems:

- A taking 50% that you didn't know was there
- B taking 25% that you did suspect was there
- C taking 12.5% that you didn't know was there

So what's your strategy?

If you prematurely fix B, you will save 25%, for a 1.33x speed gain over not having fixed it.
You could be happy with that, but...

If you follow a process of diagnosis, which I recommend, it doesn't mean don't fix B.
It means first let the diagnosis surprise you by pointing out A.
If you fix that first, you save 50%, which gives you a 2x speed gain.

What's more, when you do the diagnosis again, it says now B is taking 50% of the time, not 25%, so it not only tells you you were right, fixing it gives you another 2x speed gain, not just 1.33x. So after fixing A and B, you are 4x faster.
(Of course, if you fixed B first and then fixed A, you'd end up at the same place.)

Finally, whether or not you had guessed that C was a problem but not a very big one, now it is a big one because you already fixed A and B. Now C takes 50% of the time, not 12.5%, so fixing it gives you *yet another* 2x speedup.
So now you're 8x faster than you were at the beginning.

This is all a result of the method you use for finding the problems *you didn't anticipate*.
***Those are where the money is.***
[*Here's an example of a 730x speedup*](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/1870/1262), by fixing a succession of six problems, some of which, at the beginning, were really small, but together, they add up to *over 99.8% of* the time.

Of course, you learn from this, and you avoid the pitfalls and write faster code to start with, which I suppose you could call premature optimization :)

Answer (score 1):

As is, the code won't compile! When `parent->ExecuteParent()` is called, `MyClass` isn't defined. That said, if the order of the declarations and definitions is sorted out and the functions are suitably defined as `inline` the compiler *can* inline them: the methods `ExecuteParent()` and `ExecuteChild()` are known at compile time they aren't `virtual`. Whether the compiler *will* inline the function is a different matter.